# $\frac{0}{0}$ Indeterminate

Tags: calculus

I confused myself a little bit the other day explaining to someone why $\frac{0}{0}$ is defined, but not well-determined. I know the standard explanation is $y\cdot 0=0$ for all real $y$.

First, why $\frac{x}{0}$ is undefined for $x\neq 0$. The reason is $0$ doesn't have a multiplicative inverse: For suppose there is does, i.e. $0\cdot 0^{-1}=1$, then form the product $\frac{x}{0}=x\cdot 0^{-1}$. Then

\begin{align}
&\frac{x}{0}=C \\
\implies &0\cdot\frac{x}{0}=0\cdot C \\
\implies &0\cdot(x\cdot 0^{-1})=0\cdot C \\
\implies &0\cdot(0^{-1}\cdot x)=0 \\
\implies &(0\cdot0^{-1})\cdot x=0 \\
\implies &1\cdot x=0 \\
\end{align}
Contradiction.

So for $x\neq 0$, we can't define $x\cdot 0^{-1}$ because $0^{-1}$ isn't defined. Now returning to my question, if $0^{-1}$ isn't defined, how is it that  $0\cdot 0^{-1}$ can be defined at all?

Comment: It isn't defined.

Comment: It depends on context. If there is none, then it is simply undefined. But you often have $h(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, where $f(0)=g(0)=0$, but $\lim_{x\to0} h(x)$ has a well-defined value. In that case you obviously take that value as $h(0)$.

Comment: $\frac{0}{0}$ can be defined, but not if you are only considering the symbol $\frac{0}{0}$.  For example, if we are to talk about $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2}{x} = \frac{0}{0} = 0,$ the symbol $\frac{0}{0}$ is perfectly well defined, as long as someone knows what it is standing for, in this case a limit that tends to zero. Likewise, $\lim_{x\to 0 } \frac{x}{x} = \frac{0}{0} = 1$ is also defined.  My point is that when $\frac{0}{0}$ is well defined, there needs to be more information defining it.  Also, I'm only talking about the reals here, no obscure fields with non standard definitions.

Comment: @Merkh: What you're talking about is not defining the symbol $\frac00$ -- it is true enough that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2}{x} = 0$, but the left-hand side of this **does not equal** $\frac00$, and treating the fact that the limit exists as if that constitutes a definition of $\frac00$ will serve no purpose at all; rather it will just hopelessly confuse readers who don't know enough to recognize the claim as the nonsense it is.

Comment: The notion "indeterminate form" relates to the fact that $a_n\to 0$, $b_n\to 0$ does not tell us much about the limit of $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$. Howver, $\frac 00$ is also "undefined" for the simple reason that it is not immediately defined per the usual definition of $\frac ab$ as the unique solution (if it exists) of $b\cdot x=a$. Lacking uniqueness in the case $a=b=0$, this definition does not cover $\frac 00$. -- In contrast to this, $0^0$ is an "indeterminate form" (in the unkown-limit-sense above), but it is defined (contrary to somewhat popular belief)

Comment: In general it isn't defined. However you may find some proof where $\frac{0}{0}$ is defined (usually as $0$ or $1$) in order to ease a proof involving $\frac{a}{b}$ and avoid a case analysis when $a=b=0$. But $\frac{0}{0}$ is not defined.

Comment: @Henning We can just as well say $\frac{0}{0}$ is nonsense and has no meaning, sure.  But if one \textit{wants} to define it in some context, one can by treating $\frac{0}{0}$ as a symbol with a specific meaning.  Similar to saying $\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i\xi x} \; d\xi = \delta(x),$ this is a "symbolic" representation of the delta functional, not meant to be interpreted as the $\delta(x)$ function being genuinely equal to a divergent integral.  In the same way, we can treat $\frac{0}{0}$ as having meaning if we are careful about it.

Comment: @Merkh: One reason why I feel strongly about not blithely writing $=\frac00$ here is that doing so perpetuates the fallacy that one should _in general_ expect that $$ \lim_{x\to c} F(g(x),h(x)) = F(\lim_{x\to c}g(x),\lim_{x\to c} h(x))$$ (here in the particular case that $F$ denotes division). But this is emphatically not true -- in fact we have a name for functions where this _is_ valid; they're called _continuous_ and are pretty important. Writing $=\frac00$ will just condition students _not_ to verify that functions are continuous at the relevant points when they do things like the above.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The expression $$\frac{0}{0}$$ is undefined *period* because $0^{-1}$ is not defined (due to the fact that $0 \neq 1$ in $\mathbb{R}$).

Many people bring up limits when they discuss this. I believe this is fundamentally misleading because, with limits, we study the behaviour of the numerator and the denominator as they tend to $0$, not when they are $0$. Thus, one may have $f,g \to 0$ as $x \to c$ so that

$$\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$ may be well-defined, but we are in no formal sense dividing $0$ by $0$ in this situation.

Comment: More specifically, the expression $0/0$ usually denotes an indeterminate form, i.e. an expression like $f(x)/g(x)$ such that $f(0)=g(0)=0$. The expression has indeed no value in the ordinary sense, but it is implicit that you can resolve the indeterminate form by taking the limit, if it exists.